# How to add collaborator for Meteor package in Atmosphere

Tags: meteor, atmosphere.js

I have posted a package into [atmospherejs](http://atmospherejs.com). Package was done in collaboration with a few people. How to add them as collaborators there?

Also it could be good to publish package as an organisation. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best indeed to publish the packages as an organization. That is the approach I'm recommending especially for 3rd party libraries. For example, I'm the sole contributor right now to [webix:webix](https://atmospherejs.com/webix/webix), but that may change in the future, and in any case, the credit should go to [webix](/questions/tagged/webix), not me.

To create an organization, go to [Meteor -> My Account -> Organizations](https://www.meteor.com/account-settings/organizations). Add a new organization, then add members to it.

No need for `meteor admin maintainers`. However, run `meteor admin help maintainers` for available operations.

Answer (score 3):

```
meteor admin maintainers <yourusername:your-package> --add <collaboration-username>

meteor admin maintainers iron:router --add mrt
```

Comment: While the `mrt` example is syntactically correct, it should be avoided. `mrt` is a deprecated username from the old `meteorite` days.